# How tomreverse a string in python?

Tags: python, string

I have a string:

```
ahdeg
```

What is the best way to reverse a string in python so it would be:

```
gedha
```

Anything would help, thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Say you have a string.

`string = 'Test'`

`string[::-1]` would reverse this into 'tseT'

Comment: There was a typo. Not sure why this is downvoted.

Comment: maybe because it's an answer to a question marked as a duplicate, and adds nothing beyond the top answer to the duplicate...